# Hmac Authentication in Browsers

Tags: rest, security, hmac

I am building a rest api and i want to secure my apis and wanted to use HMAC authentication.

My doubt is, should Hmac authentication be used only for integration with third party api's or can they securely be used in the browser also.

If yes,
how to securely share api secret from server to browser.
Is it safe to directly send this secret over HTTPS?

It would be great if someone who has experience with hmac authentication in browsers can tell some flow and advantages/disdvantages of this approach.

Thanks

Comment: Please ask on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: done...thanks @YannDroneaud

Comment: Can you link your question please @piyushpruthi ? I couldn't find it